# org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am trying to configure hibernate in Eclipse but i am having some problems when i try to generate the Hibernate Code:

> org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a
>   NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is
>   incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class Received
>   a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath
>   is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
>   org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a
>   NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is
>   incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class Received
>   a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath
>   is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap
>   org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap cannot be found by
>   org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_1_5.0.1.Final-v20160331-1852-B88
>   org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap cannot be found by
>   org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_1_5.0.1.Final-v20160331-1852-B88

[This is how my projects libraries look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L82hP.jpg)

And this is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="ConexionHibernate">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hr</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hr</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Before i have it with a tons more of jar files, but looking in other topics i tried to delete them. Before i had this jars, just in case i deleted someone i should not.

[Old version of my project library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeQGC.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Friend, use maven or gradle to handle your dependencies.

Comment: Is just a small application to start using Hibernate, as i know, Maven is not necessary for what i am doing and also, i do not know how to implement it to solve the problem. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve the problem.

First of all i downloaded again all the jars from the hibernate website http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/, concretely the 5.1.1 version.

I added to my project all the jars, not just the ones from the required folder, as i did the first time. And finally i downgraded the Hibernate console version to 4.3 and whoala! its working!